# fnmatch only returning the first filename in my list

Tags: python

Python beginner here and I'm losing my mind..
I started writing a script that starts by searching through an .edl, strips the necessary data and saves the results to a list.

After that's done, I need the script to create a new list with all the absolute paths of the files i'm looking for but it only keeps returning the first file in my list without going further.

I've tried messing around with re. / fnmatch / glob() but I keep running into similar issues.

```py
import re
import os
import fnmatch

edlname = input("EDL Filename: ")
rootPath = input("Directory of Quicktimes: ")
names = []
linenum = 0
pattern_name = re.compile("NAME", re.IGNORECASE)

with open(edlname, 'rt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        linenum += 1
        if pattern_name.search(line) != None:
            names.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
    for err in names:
        filename_list = (err[1].replace("* FROM CLIP NAME: ", "").replace("_MOV", ".mov"))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filename_list):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

the result I'm getting:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.6262.63)
EDL Filename: my.edl
Directory of Quicktimes: /Volumes/path/
/Volumes/path/JQNA0417000H.mov
/Volumes/path/path/JQNA0417000H.mov
/Volumes/path/path2/JQNA0417000H.mov
/Volumes/path/path3/JQNA0417000H.mov
```

First issue is that it should move on after the first match ( which I'm sure I can figure out eventually ) but my bigger issue is that it only takes the very first clipname, searches, finds it and doesn't continue the list..

I'm really motivated to learn python but I've been pulling my hair out trying.. I feel like every tiny win turns straight into the next disaster and I'm sure the piece of code I wrote so far is laughable, but I guess the best thing to do is just to keep marching on. Was this also a problem when you guys started out? Sigh.. I've got a lot too learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line only saves the change of the last iteration to a string variable (not list):

```
for err in names:
        filename_list = (err[1].replace("* FROM CLIP NAME: ", "").replace("_MOV", ".mov"))
```

You should declare a list at the beginning (`filename_list = []`) and also append the result to the list:

```
for err in names:
        filename_list.append((err[1].replace("* FROM CLIP NAME: ", "").replace("_MOV", ".mov")))
```

Comment: Thank you raze, really appreciate the help! Unfortunately I gave that a try earlier but it returned the following error:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: Ah you know what, I think I found a solution!
str1 = '\n'.join(str(e) for e in filename_list)
print(str1)
This seems to do the trick, and hopefully I'll be able to search for the files from my "str1" Thank you again, I've been stuck for awhile here so much appreciated!

Comment: `fnmatch.filter(files, filename_list)` needs a single string as second parameter, not a list. So you have to make a second nested iteration which go trough all filename_list elements and search for matches.

Comment: Ha you beat me to it, I just ran it with my added code and it wasn't giving me any errors but it also didn't return anything: "Process finished with exit code 0"
I'll keep playing with it and see if I can add the nested iteration. Thanks again for the tips, I'm very grateful.

Comment: No worries! Please write if this solutions worked that I can update my answer for other reader.

Comment: dang it, i'm still lost. when I added the .append it started duplicating a lot of the filenames and created a big list ( presumably because of the names.append line? ) so removing it creates the list I want again, but I'm stuck on how to make a second nested iteration that allows me to input every line into the fnmatch.filter. Could you steer me in the right direction? Thanks again!